# How to Connect to client's ADFS from azure active directory

Tags: angularjs, azure, adfs, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

We are developing a SaaS web application with an Angular UI front end and my login works just fine with the users I have added in my Azure Active directory as well as users from any other Azure AD using it's consent framework and everything is sweet.

What I now need is to allow users to login using ADFS of other organization which does not have any Azure Active directory. Which is the best solution for this?

For a test, I created a local active directory in a VM and federated it using ADFS. Let's say otherorganizationdomain.com is the doman. Even though I can access the login page directly using the URL I got during my ADFS set up, but when I typed that domain name(xxx@otherorganizationdomain.com) in my multi tenant app's login page it is not getting redirected to the login page of my ADFS where as other login continues to work fine.

I have a multitenant web app in the Azure AD. What I would ideally like to happen is when I type xxx@otherorganizationdomain.com I should be redirected to their ADFS login page and comes back with the claim just like how it works with Azure Active Directory. Am I trying to do some thing which can't be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You could federate ADFS as per [ADFS : Using Azure AD](https://cloudidentityblog.com/2013/07/19/waad-as-idp/)  but Azure AD is always the IDP which isn't what you want.

You could use AD Connect and sync. the users up but that is normally designed for users in the same forest. This is the way O365 works. Federated domains redirect to ADFS.

Or you could use [AzureAD Pass-Through Authentication and Seamless Single Sign-on](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/12/07/introducing-azuread-pass-through-authentication-and-seamless-single-sign-on/).

This uses your local DC but not ADFS.

Comment: Since it is a MT application, how do I handle authentication with multiple organization's DC using the Azure AD pass through method ?

Comment: The other tenant need to run AD Connect on on-premise AD ?